# Find a countable family of closed intervals contained in $[0,1]$ such that the union covers $[0,1]$ but there is no finite subcover.

Tags: real-analysis

The question is

> Find a countable family of closed intervals contained in $[0,1]$ such that the union covers $[0,1]$ but there is no finite subcover.

My solution is $\bigcup[\frac{1}{n},1]\bigcup[0,0]\}$. I am not sure if this is correct. Does $[0,0]$ counts as an interval?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? By all sensible definitions of an interval, both one-point sets and the empty set are intervals.

Comment: Use your above "trick" but instead of converging on zero, converge on 1/2.  Then you don't have to worry about the particular definition of interval.

Comment: @Nitin, these intervals don't need to be disjoint.